# React - Get displayName of functional component inside the component?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to get the name of a functional component inside it?

Something like:

```
function CarWasher(props) {
  const handleOnPress = () => {
    console.log(this.displayName); // <-- Something like this displayName
  }

  return ...JSX;
};

CarWasher.displayName = "CarWasher";
```

Comment: `console.log(CarWasher.displayName)`? (but why not just log `"CarWasher"` then?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't like literals. Imagine using the same string multiple times, there might be typo errors etc. you know. I was asking for a way to do that in order to avoid creating a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the `.name` property of the function.

```js
function CarWasher(props) {
  const handleOnPress = () => {
    console.log(CarWasher.name);
  }
  handleOnPress();
};

CarWasher();
```

If you're worried about accidentally making a typo when referencing one of the above variables, consider using TypeScript or at least the [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) ESLint rule.

Answer (score 0):

Also, with displayName:

```js
function MemoizedCarWasher(props) {
  const handleOnPress = () => {
    console.log(MemoizedCarWasher.displayName);
  }

  handleOnPress();
};

MemoizedCarWasher.displayName = "CarWasher";

MemoizedCarWasher();
```